# Add UIStackView as a customview of a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: swift, uikit, uitoolbar

I try to add a `UIStackView` as a custom view of a `UIBarButtonItem`.

I first tried adding a `UIView` as the custom view.

```
let list = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 44))
list.backgroundColor = .green
list.addSubview(stackView)
let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: list )
topViewController?.setToolbarItems([item], animated: true)
```

This works. I get a green bar in the `UIToolBar`. Then I tried adding a `UIStackView` to the `UIView`.

```
let red = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 30))
red.backgroundColor = .red
let stackView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero,
                                         size: CGSize(width: 250, height: 44)))
stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
stackView.axis = .horizontal
stackView.spacing = 5
stackView.alignment = .center
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
stackView.addArrangedSubview(red)
let list = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 44))
list.backgroundColor = .green
list.addSubview(stackView)
let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: list )
topViewController?.setToolbarItems([item], animated: true)
```

However, when I try this, nothing happens. The `UIToolBar` seems empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use multiple items instead of trying to put it all inside a stack view ?

Comment: @LeoDabus For the spacing between them. I couldn't find a good way to change the spacing between the individual items in a `UIToolBar`, so I thought this was the second-best solution.

Comment: You can use a flexible width item if needed

Comment: @LeoDabus Well, I need less space then the default width between items. So that's why.

Comment: didnt run your code but it seems ok for me, btw you can see if constraints will work / not

Comment: @Sh_Khan Allright, man. Clearly it's not working for me, though.

Comment: @user4992124 .Is my answer useful??

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, I have used two `UIViews`.

You have to give `height constraints` for two `UIViews`

```
red.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true;
green.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true;
```

You have to comment this line,

```
//stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

**Full Code:**

```
    self.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false

    let red = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 30))
    red.backgroundColor = .red
    let green = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 30))
    green.backgroundColor = .green

    red.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true;
    green.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true;

    let stackView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 30))
    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.spacing = 5
    stackView.alignment = .center
    //stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(red)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(green)

    let list = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 44))
    list.backgroundColor = .yellow
    list.addSubview(stackView)
    let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: list )
    self.setToolbarItems([item], animated: true)
```

**Output:**

[image]